# DH: Is it possible to solve for A private if all other variables are known with 90-bit modulus

Tags: diffie-hellman, discrete-logarithm, algebraic-attack, pollard-rho

$g^{ab} \pmod{p} = B^a \pmod{p}$ where all variables are known except $a$. In this case, I have an equivalent value for $a'*b'$, but this is not the same as the real values of $a*b$ due to the modulus.

Everything else including the generator, the prime, $B$ public, the shared secret (or value of both sides of the equation) are known.

Since $p$ is a 90-bit value, this is would be difficult to calculate, but if there is some $\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n})$ optimization, this may put it on the edge of the possibility to brute force.

Comment: 90-bit is too easy even for ECDH.

Comment: Looks like a challenge from a competition..

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, this is totally feasible. Unless $p$ is purposely chosen as a [safe prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes), there's a good chance that's easy.

Computing $a$ given $B$, $p$, and $C=B^a\bmod p$ is a [Discrete Logarithm Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm) in the [multiplicative group modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) prime¹ $p$, of order $r=p-1$.

For any DLP problem, there is a generic attack of cost a few times $\sqrt r$ group operations, [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard%27s_rho_algorithm_for_logarithms). Not only is $2^{\approx45}$ multiplications modulo 90-bit $p$ feasible, but that can be efficiently distributed on independent machines, see Paul C. van Oorschot and Michael J. Wiener's [*Parallel Collision Search with Cryptanalytic Applications*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/PL00003816.pdf) (in [Journal of Cryptology, 1999](https://doi.org/10.1007/PL00003816), following their article in [proceedings of CCS 1994](https://doi.org/10.1145/191177.191231)).

Also, there is the generic [Pohlig-Hellman DLP method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm), which can help if $r$ is of known factorization.Here for we can factor the 89-bit $r/2$ in a breeze. The main DLP reduces to a few easier DLPs in groups of smaller *prime* order. These can be solved by [Baby-step/Giant-step](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby-step_giant-step) for small ones, or Pollard's rho and it's distributed variant for large ones. A typical factorization of $r$ has a largest prime factor $q$ of [multiplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicity_(mathematics)) 1 and much larger than other primes dividing $r$, so that the work is dominated by $\sqrt q$ group operations. Here, it is not told if $p$ was chosen such that $q=r/2$ is prime (which would make Pohlig-Hellman pointless), thus there is a fair chance that $q$ is sizably less than 89-bit, easing attack greatly.

There are even more efficient methods in the case of the multiplicative group $\mathbb Z_p^*$ that we target:

- The [index calculus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_calculus_algorithm). I'm not familiar with it, but would say it is likely the method of choice here if $(p-1)/2$ is prime.
- The DLP variant of the [General Number Field Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve), which is the best known method for large $p$. The current GNFS DLP record is for a $795$-bit $p$ with $q=(p-1)/2$ prime (the hard case), see Fabrice Boudot, Pierrick Gaudry, Aurore Guillevic, Nadia Heninger, Emmanuel Thomé, and Paul Zimmermann's [*Comparing the difficulty of factorization and discrete logarithm: a 240-digit experiment*](https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/697.pdf), in [proceedings of Crypto 2020](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-56880-1_3).

---

¹ The question's mention of [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) suggests $p$ is prime. If not, we can factor $p$ into $\prod{p_i}^{\alpha_i}$, solve for $a_i$ the problems $B^{a_i}\equiv C\pmod{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$, then use the Chinese Remainder Theorem modulo the ${p_i}^{\alpha_i-1}\,(p_i-1)$ to find a solution $a$.